# create postgis extension syntax error at or near "PARALLEL"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When I try to enable the postgis extension in postgresql on windows I get the following error:

> syntax error at or near "PARALLEL"

I have been looking, but cannot find anyone with this error. Any help?

Comment: It seems you are using a PostGIS version that is intended for Postgres 9.6 but you are using an earlier Postgres version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I had PostgreSQL 9.5 installed, I was using PostGIS intended for version 9.6. This caused the error.

Credits to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)

Comment: You can use [Pex](https://github.com/petere/pex) to install a version of PostGIS that matches your existing postgres version.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same error and solved it with the good old restart procedure:

```
# install or upgrade postgres and postgis
brew upgrade postgres
brew upgrade postgis

# drop extension in case of an update
DROP EXTENSION postgis

# restart postgres
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

# create extension
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

I think restarting postgres was the important step to resolve the issue.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name mentioned as a comment below my answer, the problem is the version mismatch. The upgrade commands you use probably solve the problem rather than the restart

Comment: I was getting this error but *without* a version mismatch. Restarting the PostgreSQL 'cluster' (server instance) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

I had an old version of Postgres. This did solve the problem on osx.